# Unescape Form data in PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I am new to Laravel and OctoberCMS. I have a form that submits to a controller to search on slug keyword from a model. The problem I'm facing is the `post('slug')` seems to be escaped.

```php
return Blog::where('title', '=', 'Ben bott 2019')
    ->where('slug', '=', 'ben-bott-2019')->get();
```

It works when I try the above manually.

---

**HTML**

```php
<form action="/search" method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
    Slug: <input type="text" name="slug"><br>
    <input type="submit">
```

**ControllerBlogs.php**

```php
class Blogs extends Controller
{
    public $implement = ['Backend\Behaviors\FormController'];

    public function search()
    {
        return Blog::where('title', '=', post('title'))
            ->where('id', '=', post('slug'))->get();
    }
}
```

---

**Blog.php** > extends October Model (Can access all eloquent methods)

```php
class Blog extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    protected $table = 'blogs';

    public $rules = [];
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::any('search', 'Novaji\Andre\Controllers\Blogs@search');
```

It seems to be escaping the slug and returning empty JSON (Fails when I submit via form post).

Comment: Should't `->where('id','=', post('slug'))` really be `->where('slug','=', post('slug'))`, like you have in your "manual" test that you say actually work?

Comment: How do you know they're still encoded in the controller? Can you verify your theory by using `urldecode`?

Comment: Thanks bro..... I didnt see it. I think i really need to get a replacement for ma broken glasses *sobs*